# How to create SVG from PNG

Tags: svg, bitmap, png, inkscape

I've been using inkscape to create SVGs. But I've come across a problem. I've created a simple plus sign with a 1px line width (as simple as you can imagine). It is currently in PNG format with a transparent background. I've imported it into inkscape so I can convert it into a SVG. However, when I use trace bitmap, Inkscape CHANGES THE SHAPE such that the straight lines that are one pixel wide are tappered with pointed ends! I've tried different options in the trace bitmap settings but nothing seems to work. I've also gone through a number of online free conversion sites with no luck.

I wouldn't mind just creating the plus sign using html and css but the exact position of the lines as well as the line thickness tends to move around between chrome and firefox. It's very strange.

..Help?

Comment: You may want to clarify with graphics of some sort (which I can't do in a comment box, unfortunately). Do you mean trace as in a minus sign `-----` would be turned into the three lines (`X` characters representing the trace and `.` meaning space): `.XXXXX.`, `X.....X`, `.XXXXX.` (the middle `.....` being the minus sign you traced)? If so, you probably want to avoid tracing and just have the line on its own.

Comment: Actually, you may find it's just being intelligent with the edges, forcing them to be rounded if you increase the height. It is supposed to look nice on scaling, after all.

Comment: I dont know what you mean in your first comment. But yes, Inkscape is most definitely trying to be intelligent by smoothing lines. I just want a simple "+" sign that is crisp. Is there another program that I can use to create svg files that doesn't smooth everything?

Comment: Maybe there's a reason that I cannot fathom, but: Why don't you draw the cross in Inkscape directly? Is there compelling reason to try and vectorize a bitmap to draw a simple cross shape?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. If I create a plus sign that is 2 px thick instead of 1 px thick, inkscape does not do its smoothing thing (as long as I have unticked smoothing options). So, I do this, but draw it much bigger than what I need. Then when I load it into my website I can reduce the size of it there, and voila the 2 px width becomes 1 px width!